# Geom_text and annotate don't work in my graphical cart using ggplot2

Tags: r

I try to get a geographic cart drown in function of my data. And I get it but my problem is : How to add legend for regional map with a legend describing associated labels using ggplot2?

I need to show each region's name annotated by integers.

for example : 1: Paris
           and 1 is located the cart .

My code is:

```
    library(maps)
    library(maptools)
    library(scales)
    IleFrance <- map_data('france',region=c("Paris","Seine-et-Marne","Yvelines","Essonne","Hauts-de-Seine","Seine-Saint-Denis","Val-de-Marne","Val-DOise"))
    v1=rep(1256,each=18)
    v2=rep(833,each=26)
    v3=rep(540,each=71)
    v4=rep(523,each=30)
    v5=rep(488,each=76)
    v6=rep(379,each=124)
    v7=rep(348,each=30)
    v8=rep(302,each=63)
    x=IleFrance$long
    y=IleFrance$lat
    Effectif=c(v8,v3,v6,v4,v2,v1,v7,v5)
    ggplot(IleFrance, aes(x, y))+
      geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill =Effectif))
```

This work and it give me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyyJo.png

But I want some thing like this:

[enter image description here][2]

So that I add this code:

```
c1=c(1:8)
    c2=c("Paris","Hauts-de-Seine","Yvelines","Val-de-Marne","Essonne","Seine-et-Marne","Seine-Saint-Denis","Val-DOise")        
    lat1=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==6),"lat"])
    long1=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==6),"long"])
    lat2=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==5),"lat"])
    long2=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==5),"long"])
    lat3=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==2),"lat"])
    long3=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==2),"long"])
    lat4=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==7),"lat"])
    long4=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==7),"long"])
    lat5=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==8),"lat"])
    long5=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==8),"long"])
    lat6=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==3),"lat"])
    long6=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==3),"long"])
    lat7=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==4),"lat"])
    long7=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==4),"long"])
    lat8=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==1),"lat"])
    long8=mean(IleFrance[which(IleFrance$group==1),"long"])  
    long1=c(long1,long2,long3,long4,long5,long6,long7,long8)
    lat1=c(lat1,lat2,lat3,lat4,lat5,lat6,lat7,lat8)
    df2=data.frame(lat1,long1,c1,c2)
```

So  I create new data frame to plot as the precedent cart so i did like this:

```
ggplot(IleFrance, aes(x, y))+
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill =value))+
  geom_text(data=df2,aes(x=lat1,y=long1,label=c1,group=c1), size=4)+
  annotate("text", x=1.5, y=48,
           label=paste(df2$c1,":",df2$c2,sep=""),
           size=1, hjust=0)
```

but it 's working please need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(IleFrance, aes(x, y))+
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill =Effectif)) +
  geom_text(data=df2, aes(x=long1,y=lat1,label=paste(c1, c2, sep=":")), size=3, hjust=0)
```

[image]